# Is it necessary to call Dispose on a Semaphore?

Tags: .net, multithreading, dispose, semaphore

```
class myclass 
{
    private Semaphore _sync;

    myclass ()
    {
          _sync = new Semaphore(1,1);
    }

    doasync()
    {
           _sync.WaitOne();
           //do some stuff
           _sync.Release();
    }
}


 somefunctionsomewhere() 
 {
     var myobject = new myclass();    
     //spawn 100 threads that all call myobject.doasync()
 }
```

is the above safe + clean? Will the both _sync get disposed and myclass be collected when all 100 threads have finished doing their async work?

If not, what's the best way to know when to call _sync.Dispose() ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Short answer: No, you don't need to call Dispose().

Long answer:

Though it is recommended to call Dispose() when you are finished using the Semaphore, the garbage collector will take care of the semaphore's resources sooner or later.

An explicit call to Dispose() will guarantee an early release of the associated resource, but it's only required if you are creating and *forgetting* a lot of Semaphore instance in a short amount of time.

And if you call Dispose(), it is perfectly fine to use a simple Dispose() call. You don't need  to create a finalizer `~myclass()` because that would just duplicate what's  already done the Semaphore implementation.

Comment: I like this answer better because obviously I don't want to do extra work if the GC will eventually take care of it. Semi-contradicts other answer so will wait for confirmation by 3rd party before accepting.

Comment: Its not just that the GC might get it, Its also that Dispose cleans up any unmanaged resources used by the class so it's not necessarily safe to assume the GC will deal with it.

Comment: But semaphore contains private member that is unmanaged "m_waitHandle" and if you wont call Dispose() on created SemaphoreSlim then m_waitHandle won't be closed. So you might run into some memory leaks. That shouldn't be accepted answer.  
Sauce code: 
https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/threading/SemaphoreSlim.cs#L871

Comment: m_waitHandle is a ManualResetEvent and ... going deep down the rabbit hole, you'll find a finalizer that will release it, I've found one here: https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/runtime/interopservices/safehandle.cs#L197

Comment: It wont, because finalizer calls Dispose(false), and m_waitHandle is released only when Dispose is called with true.

Answer (score 3):

If a class implements IDisposable, you really should dispose of it correctly.   It is not just about relying on the garbage collector, the disposable class could have open handles / COM objects that need to be correctly cleaned up that you cannot guarantee that the GC will handle.

Ideally you should make `myclass` implement IDisposable and clean up your disposable objects in the dispose method. If you truly cannot determine when to dispose your instance of `myclass` then you can implement logic in the destructor method for `myclass` to call the dispose method.

```
public class myclass : IDisposable
   {
   private Semaphore _sync;

    myclass ()
    {
          _sync = new Semaphore(1,1);
    }

    doasync()
    {
           _sync.WaitOne();
           //do some stuff
           _sync.Release();
    }

    public void Dispose()
       Dispose(true);
       GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    {

    protected void Dispose(bool isDisposing)
    {
       var sync=Interlocked.Exchange(ref _sync,null);
       if (sync !=null) sync.Dispose();
    }


    // This is for when you cannot determine when to dispose of your object
    void ~myclass() {
       Dispose(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: Would GC take care of it eventually though as other answer suggests?

Comment: The GC should take care of it.  It's all down to what you consider best coding practices.  I believe enabling Code Analysis will throw an error about wrapping the disposable and not disposing properly

Comment: ok thanks. will upvote this one and accept the other, since it's starts with a more direct answer. thanks for the code!

Comment: You don't need to implement `IDisposable` in your class because `Semaphore` already implements it.

Comment: @Monsingor No, you need to make your class implement IDisposable because the semaphore is private.  You make your calss implement IDisposable so that the dispose method on the semaphore is called

Comment: @HarryMexican I've also realised that my previous comment about GC handling was not necessarily correct.  The point of IDisposable is that the dispose method cleans up any unmanaged resources and so won't necessarily be GC correctly.

Comment: @Bob Vale Sorry, I meant that you don't need to implement the finalizer.

Comment: @Monsingor If you read the paragraph before the code, I state that  If you truly cannot determine when to dispose your instance of myclass then you can implement logic in the destructor (finalizer) method for myclass to call the dispose method. The key point is your code should dispose of disposable objects because there could be COM in the code behind

Comment: @Bob Vale There is no need to implement a finalizer to just call `Dispose` of a child object. This has no sense since by the time `GC` calls the finalizer your object and all its children are considered garbage. This whole tree will be destroyed during the same `GC` run. You should implement finalizer *only* in case your class directly uses *unmanaged* resources. The `Semaphore` is a managed resource, it will take care of its disposing itself.